# Use series to approximate the definite integral I. (Round your answer to three decimal places.)

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

**Use series to approximate the definite integral $I$. (Round your answer to three decimal places.)
$$I=\int _0^1x \cos\left(x^4\right) \, dx$$

I understand:
$$\int _0^1x \cos(x^2) \, dx=\frac{\sin(1)} 2 \quad \left(\text{Decimal: } 0.42074\ldots \right) = 0.421$$

But when $x$ is to the power of $4$ would it just be:

$$\int _0^1x\cos(x^4) \, dx=\frac{\sin(1)} 4 \quad \left(\text{Decimal: } 0.210 \right)$$

Comment: I don't think your second integral is correct. The first integral follows because $\frac d {dx} [\sin(x^2) /2] = x\cos(x^2)$; the second integral will not have a simple antiderivative. From the wording of the problem, it sounds like they want you to use a Taylor or MacLaurin series to approximated the integrand. Which function has a nice Taylor series in the integral?

Comment: @TrevorNorton The second integral is not correct because I tried submitting it and it didn't work. I'm currently learning about Taylor and MacLaurin series so I'm not exactly sure how to answer your question. I don't know the steps well enough to figure out the answer for $\int _0^1x\cos \left(x^4\right)dx=$

Comment: You seem to have missed the phrase "Use series".

Comment: @MichaelHardy Where?

Comment: The idea is to approximate the function $x\cos(x^4)$ with a series and then evaluate. We could try figuring out the MacLaurin or Taylor series of $x\cos(x^4)$ and then integrating that term-by-term, but that would require a lot of work. However, $\cos(x)$ has a well know MacLaurin expansion. This can help us approximate the function with less work... Do you see how?

Comment: Use the Taylor series for $\cos(x)$ to get the Taylor series for $x\cos(x^4)$ (note that if $f(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + \ldots$ then $f(x^4) = a_0 + a_1 x^4 + a_2x^8 + \ldots$). Integrate this series term by term over $[0,1]$ and you are left with an alternating series for which it's easy to estimate the error by capping it after $n$ terms.

Comment: @TaljanaD : What you did does not use series. See my answer below.

Comment: this is a Fresnel integral

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It said "Use series".

You have
$$
\cos x = 1 - \frac{x^2} 2 + \frac{x^4}{24} - \frac{x^6}{720} + \cdots.
$$
So
\begin{align}
\cos(x^4) & = 1 - \frac{(x^4)^2} 2 + \frac{(x^4)^4}{24} - \frac{(x^4)^6}{720} + \cdots \\[10pt]
& = 1 - \frac{x^8} 2 + \frac{x^{16}}{24} - \frac{x^{24}}{720} + \cdots
\end{align}
and then
$$
x\cos(x^4) = x - \frac{x^9} 2 + \frac{x^{17}}{24} - \frac{x^{25}}{720} + \cdots
$$
Integrate that from $0$ to $1$ and notice that after a few terms the alternating positive and negative amounts being added are so small that they cannot change the first three digits after the decimal point.

Comment: $\int _0^1x \cos(x^2) \, dx=\frac{\sin(1)} 2 \quad \left(\text{Decimal: } 0.42074\ldots \right) ≈ 1/2-1/12+1/240 ≈0.421$

So which numbers would I add up in order to find the answer with $x^4$

Comment: I tried replacing the value of x by 1, and got 0.540 but it didn't work.

Comment: $$ \int_0^1 \left( x - \frac{x^9} 2 + \frac{x^{17}}{24} - \frac{x^{25}}{720} + \cdots \right) \, dx = \left[ \frac{x^2} 2 - \frac{x^{10}}{20} + \frac{x^{18}}{408} - \frac{x^{26}}{18000} + \cdots \right]_0^1 $$ $$ = \frac 1 2 - \frac 1 {20} + \frac 1 {408} - \frac 1 {18000} + \cdots $$ All partial sums after that are between the sum of the first three terms and the sum of the first four terms, and so they differ from each other by less than $1/18000. \qquad$

Comment: So the final answer should be ≈0.452? Correct?

Comment: I know that this is an older question, but @michaelHardy how do you this if the function is not alternating. For example $$\int_{1}^{2} \frac{e^x}{x} dx$$ to four decimal places. Since this continues to add up until convergence, how do I know when to stop for the accuracy since even $$ln2-ln1$$ is an approximation. Its a horrible approximation but one still the same which would be the 1st term in the taylor expansion.

Comment: @Washingtonstateone : Sometimes every tail end of such series is bounded above by a geometric series. Also, you can use the standard theorem on error bounds on Taylor series.